# how to remove a specific game object (that is in an array) from a list?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine

my goal with the code is to have multiple skulls appear on screen for comparison. Depending on number of skulls on screen (1-6) they change position and size, Ive done this through the use of an array of gameObjects (the skulls) and a list that can keep track of which skull is in which "position".

The code works if you are adding, but runs into problems when you remove the object. It "works" on *RemoveAt* only if you remove the GameObjects in the same order that they were added. IE: The list is always removing *element 0*(first item in list) rather than the specific gameObject that is instigating the *RemoveAt* function.

While I have found many answers on how to remove specific individual gameObjects, They dont work since my gameObjects are in an array- I cant simply say *remove gameObject name*. Which leads me to my question of how to remove a specific gameObject[] from a list?

either *remove* or *removeAll* run these two errors:

*error CS1502:* The best overloaded method match for `System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityEngine.GameObject>.RemoveAll(System.Predicate<UnityEngine.GameObject>)' has some invalid arguments.

Error CS1503: Argument`#1' cannot convert `int' expression to type`System.Predicate'

Here are my two scripts for all this:

Script on each bird skull named *birdController*:

```
public int myBirdID;
public int orderInList;

//bool to keep track of object active or not
public bool whoAmIReally;
//potentially redundant; allows game object to see if hes on or not
public GameObject IAmMe;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    //fixingIntOrder();
}

public void OnEnable(){
    //when object is on check bool
        whoAmIReally = true;
        Debug.Log("IM ON");
}
    public void OnDisable(){
    //when object is turned off uncheck bool, change list value to 0
            //**this wont change actual list order or value in cubeplacement script- my hope is that it might have- likely missing a step somewhere
        whoAmIReally = false;
        orderInList = 0;
        Debug.Log("IMOFF");
}
```

Script on empty with all of my array and list info named *cubePlacement*:

```
    public int numberSkullOnScreen;
    public bool[] skullOn;
    public GameObject[] allSkulls;

    public GameObject listHolder;

    public List<GameObject> birdsOnScreen = new List<GameObject>();


//declaring the script to avoid NullReferenceEcxeption where I reference it 
public birdController _birdController;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //only way I can get my list to work: have an object act as a placeholder onStart
        birdsOnScreen.Add(listHolder);
    }

//turning on and off the skulls
    public void toggleBirdSkull(int mySkull){
        if (skullOn[mySkull] == false){
            //set specific gameObject active
            allSkulls[mySkull].SetActive(true);
            //make skull on bool true 
            skullOn[mySkull] = true;
            //add one to the number on screen
            numberSkullOnScreen++;

            //reference int orderInList from Bird controller script
            allSkulls[mySkull].gameObject.GetComponent<birdController>().orderInList = numberSkullOnScreen;

            //add skull to list when turned on THIS WORKS YAY
            birdsOnScreen.Add(allSkulls[mySkull]);
            //Run function to place skulls
            placementSkulls();
        }

        else{
            allSkulls[mySkull].SetActive(false);
            skullOn[mySkull] = false;
            numberSkullOnScreen--;

            //remove skull from list when turned off-- THIS DOESNT WORK... 
            birdsOnScreen.RemoveAt(allSkulls[mySkull].gameObject.GetComponent<birdController>().orderInList);


            //Run function to place skulls based on the int number skulls on screen
            placementSkulls();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sarah, welcome to Stack overflow. I would suggest that you edit your post to produce a [minimum viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order for someone to be able to answer your question. As it stands, there is a lot of code there with a great deal of background about your problem... it's going to deter people from attempting to answer your question. You never know - you may even find an answer to your own question if you try to boil it down to a more concise post! Good luck.

Comment: Convert your array to a list on start so you can add/remove items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to remove objects using `Remove` method?
Like this:

```
birdsOnScreen.Remove (allSkulls[mySkull]);
```

Your `birdsOnScreen.RemoveAt` version also looks correct.
If you want to use `RemoveAll` method, you should pass predicate, which returns `bool`, eg:

```
birdsOnScreen.RemoveAll (bird => { return bird == allSkulls[mySkull]; } );
```

I would suggest to use `Remove` in your case, since you know the object you're removing.

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2

Also, try to increase your `numberSkullOnScreen` after you assign its value to the object's property:

```
allSkulls[mySkull].gameObject.GetComponent<birdController>().orderInList = numberSkullOnScreen;

numberSkullOnScreen++;
```

This way you won't need to use a placeholder anymore, because your indices will be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback- I did try the remove method- but I believe I wrote it wrong (looked like my current code without the 'at' in RemoveAt). I just tried the way you wrote it : `birdsOnScreen.Remove (allSkulls[mySkull]);` and it completely fixes the order issue.

Comment: **I did try the last bit to fix my placeholder issue. Initially it returns no errors, however, when a skull is turned on it returns a _ArgumentOutOfRange...Parameter:index_ that is associated with my `placementSkulls();` function and the actual line that adjusts skull position within my `if` statement. Ive written that like this: `if (numberSkullOnScreen ==1){ birdsOnScreen[1].transform.position = new Vector3(-12f, -7f, 207f);}`

Comment: If your plan was to move `bird` if there is only one `skull` on the screen, then you should try `birdsOnScreen[0]` here, because the first element in the list has index `0`.

Comment: Absolutely, makes sense to me-- Ive adjusted the code for birdsOnScreen ranging from 1-6 and all the instances inbetween and it works! Thanks for your feedback, it was very valuable!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for a similar function like in an List. You could use this:

```
public static void RemoveAt<T>(ref T[] arr, int index) {
        for (int a = index; a < arr.Length - 1; a++)
        {
            arr[a] = arr[a + 1];
        }
        Array.Resize(ref arr, arr.Length - 1);
    }
```

or if you know the Object:

```
public static T[] RemoveObjectArray<T> (this T[] arr, T ObjToRemove) {  
        int numIdx = System.Array.IndexOf(arr, ObjToRemove);
        if (numIdx == -1) return arr;
        List<T> tmp = new List<T>(arr);
        tmp.RemoveAt(numIdx);
        return tmp.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your feedback! Ive seen a few RemoveAt<T> options and shyed away from them, mostly due to my lack of knowledge with lists, _and_ how new I am to the c# world. I do hope some day in the future I will know enough to try out this method too to see if it works~